# Cassandra running cqlsh fails

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh, cassandra-2.1

I am running Cassandra 2.1.15 on a virtual machine. The problem is that I cannot run the command "cqlsh" to create tables and keyspaces. It always gives me a timeout error after 2 minutes. I want to increase the timeout of cassandra. The virtual machine has 8Gb memory and 4CPUs. These are the list of things I have tried.

1. Creating `~/.cassandra/cqlshrc` file and increasing client_timeout to 3600
2. Modifying the `/usr/bin/cqlsh.py` file and increasing `DEFAULT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT_SECONDS` and `DEFAULT_REQUEST_TIMEOUT_SECONDS` variables to 3600.
3. passing the argument -`-request-timeout 3600 --connect-timeout 3600` in cqlsh.
4. Using the IP in the listen address of `cassandra.yaml` file instead of localhost

I am aware that the performance of my virtual machine is very slow as it takes about 7 minutes to see the output of nodetool status command.

Nodetool status output:

```
Datacenter: site1

=================

Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address      Load       Tokens  Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  192.168.1.6  196.08 KB  256     100.0%            c88cf8ec-f7e1-41e1-aad0-85742c8c3ffb  RAC1
```

Also I can see no error logs in the system.log file and from netstat command I can see that the server is listening for requests on ports 9042 and 9160

```
tcp6       0      0 :::9160                 :::*                    LISTEN      32694/java      
tcp6       0      0 :::11311                :::*                    LISTEN      2237/astaire    
tcp6       0      0 :::9042                 :::*                    LISTEN      32694/java      
tcp6       0      0 192.168.1.6:7000        :::*                    LISTEN      32694/java      
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:40895         :::*                    LISTEN      32694/java      
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:7199          :::*                    LISTEN      32694/java
```

Kindly help me out.

Answer (score 0):

A 8GB+4CPU spec for C* VM is good, it should not create any bottleneck or the lag you are experiencing. One think I can think of is you HDD not having enough IO bandwidth. Try checking Disk usage in Task Manager. (I assume you are using windows as you are running a VM for C*).

There are two alternatives that you can try if disk usage is the problem.

- Switch to Docker. Docker is a lightweight VM comapred to the CentOS/ Ubuntu VM you are running. Docker quickstart is [here](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/) and Dockerfiles are [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/cassandra/).
- Try C* on windows directly, using [CCM](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/ccm-2-0-and-windows) if possible.